# Windows 2016 Active Directory Restore Not Using Windows Backup

Tags: active-directory

I have been reading online how to restore AD if ever needed and understand the process using DSRM and Windows Backups. Here is my question, what if you are not using Windows backup, but a third party solution that is not AD aware and only backing up files. How do you restore the NTDS.dit file using DSRM if DSRM do not have network access?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   As DSRM is a Windows Server and **AD role specific in-built utility**, it by default uses the backup utility, i.e., **Windows Server Backup or wbadmin role** configuration for restoring the AD services on a domain controller. Its only condition is that atleast **system state backup must be enabled** for the DC to be able to restore the server to its former state. Thus, in DSRM mode, only Windows Server Backup utility works and no others. So, once the AD services are restored using the DSRM utility, I would recommend you restore the other configurations of AD through a backup utility specific for AD, i.e., Manageengine’s Active Directory Backup and Recovery tool. For more details on its setup, please refer to the details below: -

https://www.manageengine.com/ad-recovery-manager/active-directory-backup-tool.html

•   When DSRM (Directory Services Restore Mode) is enabled, the domain controller goes in **offline mode**, i.e., its network interface card is disabled by default due to which, it is unable to access any backup file remotely. Thus, in this case, you should place the **latest and recent unaltered backup file** containing the ‘NTDS.dit’ file on a drive location locally on the domain controller itself by booting it up normally and accessing the remote network location where the concerned file is stored and copying/moving it onto the domain controller on a suitable accessible drive/directory location locally. Then, going into the DSRM mode and accessing the backup file and restoring it again on the domain controller will surely help you bring back the AD services live again.

•   Also, during DSRM mode, the domain controller is taken offline and is considered as a **member server** due to which if DNS role is also installed on it, then it becomes difficult for the DC to search for another remote location on the network due to DNS service being unaccessible. In this case, you can use the **IP address of the gateway/router** to browse through the network for any location of the backup file.

•   For detailed steps to restore the AD services during the DSRM mode, kindly refer to the below link: -

https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/08/12/restore-active-directory-system-states.aspx

Also, please refer to the official documentation link below for details on recovering the Active Directory services and considerations while configuring one: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/ad-forest-recovery-determine-how-to-recover

Comment: Thank you for great  response!!!! I do have a question regarding the following comment...."As DSRM is a Windows Server and AD role specific in-built utility, it by default uses the backup utility, i.e., Windows Server Backup or wbadmin role configuration for restoring the AD services on a domain controller. Its only condition is that at least system state backup must be enabled for the DC to be able to restore the server to its former state" So DSRM only work with Windows Backup  I did not know this. So if you have a DC that does have have Windows Backup running you are out of luck correct?

Comment: Also taking this a step further is you if wanted to restore a DC into a isolated environment i.e DR etc you could do a Full System / Bare Metal Restore then clean up AD after the fact correct?

Comment: No, if Windows Backup service is running, then system state backup will happen on the Domain Controller and you will have the option of restoring AD in DSRM from there. Yes, as a matter of fact, if you restore a DC in isolated environment and then do a full system/bare metal recovery, then cleaning up the AD isn't necessary as the latest original clean backup will be restored.

Comment: Also, if you configure an Additional domain controller in your environment, then it can be promoted to DC, and from there the original infected DC can be restored by seizing the FSMO roles on the ADC temporarily and again restoring them later.

Comment: So if Windows Backup is not enabled like I see on most of our DC's, there is no System State backup for DSRM to use correct?

Comment: To add onto this, if you are using a 3rd party backup that does get the the System State data on a DC, what would the restore process be? Restoring the DC while it is online would cause a whole host of problem I would imagine.

Comment: Yes, if Windows Backup is not enabled, then there is no system state backup available from which you can restore you DC during DSRM. Thus, if you have a system state backup using any other third-party backup software, then you can reinstall the domain controller by installing the Windows Server OS on it and then again go into DSRM mode and then install the backup from there as drive partitions will need to be cleared and checked thoroughly for that purpose.

Comment: More details here: - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb727048(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. Please follow this link for your above queries.